# HTML : How to merge rowspan if have a looping?

Tags: html, loops, html-table, row

I have a problem regarding of creating table.

I want to do this:

[image]

But I got this:

[image]

I have tried everything and I'm realize that I have problem with the looping. I've tried to put `@endforeach` before `</tr>`. But the table looks like more messy.

Here my code

```html
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
  <div class="datagrid">
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>No</th>
          <th>Booking ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Identity</th>
          <th>Diver Status</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Payment</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        @foreach($report->bookings as $booking)

        <tr>
          <td class="border" rowspan="{{count($booking->divers)}}">{{ $loop->index+1 }}</td>
          <td rowspan="{{count($booking->divers)}}">{{$booking->booking_id}}</td>

          @foreach($booking->divers as $diver)
          <td>{{$diver->name}}</td>
          <td>{{$diver->identity}}</td>
          <td>{{$diver->license}}</td>
          <td rowspan="{{count($diver->name)}}">{{$booking->status }}</td>
          <td rowspan="{{count($diver->name)}}">{{ $booking->total_fee }}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
        @endforeach


      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

How I want to merge status and payment same with no and booking id?

Answer (score 0):

I happen to have the same problem, and finished in the following way.

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($report->bookings as $booking)
    <tr>
      <td class="border" rowspan="{{count($booking->divers) + 1}}">{{ $loop->index+1 }}</td>
      <td rowspan="{{count($booking->divers) + 1}}">{{$booking->booking_id}}</td>
    </tr>
      <?php $x = ''; ?>
      @foreach($booking->divers as $diver)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$diver->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$diver->identity}}</td>
            <td>{{$diver->license}}</td>

          <?php if(empty($x)){?>
                <td rowspan="{{count($diver->name)}}">{{$booking->status }}</td>
                <td rowspan="{{count($diver->name)}}">{{ $booking->total_fee }}</td>
          <?php } ?>

        </tr>
      <?php $x = $booking->booking_id; ?>
      @endforeach
    @endforeach
```

Or if you have done, please share it with me.
I think this is not the best way.